# 19.10 installer not recognising hard drives

Tags: system-installation, hard-drive, 19.10

I am trying to install Ubuntu 19.10 onto my dad's brand new machine (it's an Acer **ConceptD CN315-71P**). It did have Windows on there but that was completely wiped, so there's currently no other OS on the system. The machine has two **WDC PC SN720 SDAPNTW-512G-1014** drives on there.

He wants me to make several partitions, for himself and his companies, but GParted only recognised the USB. When I tried a test install, I could only select the USB and neither of the two drives.

Does anyone know how I can sort this, please, as the only search results I've found thus far, relate to installing along side Windows, which is not applicable.

Answer (score 1):

I had help with this. The solution ended up involving the BIOS. I had to find **SATA Mode** and change it to **AHCI**. It was hidden under the *main* tab but was revealed by pressing **Ctrl+s**.

Comment: Suggest you click on the checkmark to the left of your answer to show it was the answer which solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the specs for that laptop, it's likely it came with Secure Boot enabled. If you have not done so, you should try booting into the BIOS and turning off Secure Boot to see if Ubuntu can install in legacy mode. Normally that shouldn't be necessary but I've had stranger things pop up on Windows 10 Pro boxes.